# How to cut HTML tags inside ng-bind-html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use `ng-bind-html` in template HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="message.message + getTemplate(message.file)"></div>
```

Can I cut HTML and others tags only for this part `message.message` inside `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: could you be a bit more specific

Comment: First, `ng-bind-html` is almost always unnecessary, and using it *probably* indicates that you aren't really coding "the angular way".  Second, it's not exactly clear what you mean by "cut HTML".

Comment: @Claies that's a strange statement about `ng-bind-html`. It's very helpful for user generated html such as from a wysiwyg editor. What alternatives would you propose for such cases?

Comment: Using it for user generated HTML is the *only* time it would really be valid; however, the vast majority of questions her on SO where the  directive is used is in some other scenario, usually for templates.  In this question in particular, there is no context to indicate that this usage would be appropriate.

Comment: I need to secure page from XSS attack